# trying the check if cin.get() leaves the end of line character in stream

Tags: c++11

1.i am trying to check whether the cin.get() leaves the end line character in stream and considered it for next input. 
i have tried this code in code blocks but unable to provide input for next string,i am attaching code i have tried and the output .could anyone please explain.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char s1[10];
    char s2[10];

    cout << "enter the first string: ";
    cin.get(s1, 10);

    cout << "enter the second string: ";
    cin.getline(s2, 10);

    cout << s1 << " " << s2;

    return 0;
}
```

enter the first string: hello

enter the second string: hello

please explain the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This `get` function reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) says that your overload is

> Same as `get(s, count, widen('\n'))`

And that overload of the function reads until (among other things)

> the next available input character `c` equals `delim`, as determined by `Traits::eq(c, delim)`. This character is **not extracted** (unlike `basic_istream::getline())`

<sub>[Emphasis mine]</sub>

So the newline is left in the input buffer, for the `getline` call to read as an "empty" line.

If you want to read lines, I suggest you use `std::string` and [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) (which does read, and throw away, the newline).

Comment: thankyou for your answer.since i am new to programming could you explain that is easy to understand

Comment: @PARUL In short, if you read a string using the `get` function, it will not read the newline.

Answer (score -1):

cin.get() grabs the newline character by default. It will not leave the newline in the stream.

Comment: The non-argument overload of `get` will read all characters, including the newline. But it's not the overload used by the OP.